# How to detect Ctrl+Enter in (neo)vim

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, macos

My system is macOS. The terminal simulator I'm using is Alacritty. I run neovim inside a tmux session. In my case, both <kbd>↵</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>↵</kbd> send `^M`(visually here, in fact it's a single char). So there is no way to differentiate them without modifying the alacritty config. Any idea?

Comment: <CR> or Enter is represented as <C-M>. So it doesn't matter if you press Ctrl yourself. The terminal is receiving a simple <C-M>. Think of it this way: you have two Ctrl buttons on your keyboard. If you press both, most if not all application will consider it as one Ctrl keypress. Same is happening here. The Enter button is pressing a Ctrl button for you.

Comment: @kadekai I think this deserves an answer and the points :) Thanks! I just came across some random comment on GitHub saying Neovim can differentiate <CR> and <C-CR>

Comment: I didn't put it as _answer_ cause I'm not 100% sure it's correct. I am sure that terminal emulators, at least normal ones, can't distinguish between <Enter> and <C-Enter>. But I am not sure vim itself cannot. Maybe gvim uses some other key-capturing tool. Maybe even terminal vim uses other key-capturing tools which bypasses the terminal somehow. Point is: I haven't looked at the code, and without doing that, my comment is just a conjecture.

Comment: @kadekai: It turns out that he/she is using Neovim Qt(I just saw the new comment today). So I think that makes it possible to distinguish the twos, and you're correct. Thanks for your carefulness on the words :)!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert but have made some progress on this issue that seems worth sharing. It's true that traditionally, terminal emulators would not distinguish between many key combinations including control-enter from enter; however, there are new "keyboard protocols" now implemented in some terminal emulators that address this issue.

The latest version of Alacritty, 0.13.0-rc1 (ada35ae), available on GitHub implements the Kitty keyboard protocol, which fixes this issue for Neovim *not* in tmux. However, tmux doesn't recognize the Kitty protocol and so this still won't work within tmux (see https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/3335, https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2705).

Tmux does recognize the "CSI u" protocol, which is available as an option in iTerm2. So if you are willing to use iTerm2, you can enable "CSI u" and then Control-Enter should work as you wish in neovim within tmux. (E.g. I am able to make keybinds with `<C-CR>` in neovim that recognize control-enter.)

more info:

- https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/keyboard-protocol/
- https://iterm2.com/documentation-csiu.html
- maybe there is an alacritty workaround based on [this suggestion](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/pull/5358#issuecomment-950413071)